# Audiogram with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to display an audiogram, but I am facing the following difficulties:

- the Y axis has the following categories 125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000. They all need to be of equal distance from each other. In other words the intervals have to be equal despite the values. This is not really a problem as I can just use categories : [....] and data:[...] and it works absolutely fine.
- The trouble is, there are 750 1500 3000 6000 values as well, but they must be displayed on the 2/3rd of the distance between the neighbouring points contrary to law of mathematics.

This is how it should look like:
[Sample](http://i678.photobucket.com/albums/vv144/gergiusz/Stack/Stack1.jpg)

This is what I got so far
[Mine](http://i678.photobucket.com/albums/vv144/gergiusz/Stack/Stack2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a combination of

- multiple x axes
- categories
- tickPositions
- axis label formatter

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/D2TPh/

```
labels: {
  formatter:function() {
    var v = this.value;
    if (v == 2.66) return '750';
    else if (v == 3.66) return '1.5k';
    else if (v == 4.66) return '3k';
    else if (v == 5.66) return '6k';
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but instead of the if's I would rather use mappings:

var map = 
         {
          "1.5K" : 1
          "3K" : 2
         }

return map[v];

Many Thanks

Comment: Actually I am not so sure now, as I can see it's essentially a dual axis, but I have the plot the 1.5K 3K 6K values as well. I think I will need to combine yours and Sebastian's solution...

Comment: The two axes are linked.  So if you need to plot the 1.5 value, you just use 3.66 as your x value, and so on.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for spending your time to this matter. This is exactly what I have been trying to achieve.

Comment: One more thing. Would you be able to help in how I can make every tick display on both axis even if some of the chart points are missing?

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D2TPh/4/ ?  if so, you can set your min to 0, and your max to the highest category index - on the *first* x axis.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a binary logarithmic Y axis (base 2).  I know Highcharts supports base 10 [logarithmic axes](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-log-axis), but a quick search didn't find how to use base 2.

What you could try is:

- Define your Y data points as LOG2(y) so that they are evenly spaced
- Use an [axis formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) to format them for display on the Y axis as pow(2,y) to display the original values.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you use `categories` you should achive the same distance between ticks.

http://jsfiddle.net/3K86L/

But you can also use tickPostitions or use tickPositioner

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: The first part is working fine, no problem. The tickpositioner seems to be the way to go then. I suppose I just need to map the string values to the actual integer positions and that's that. I feel this post will provide the solution, many thanks